# Extracting digits from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a java `String` object.

Lets say

```
String str = "5N7BS is having a number 33 and 55c";
```

Desired output: `33 55`

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("5N7BS is having a number 33 and 55");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Above code gives 5  7 33   55 as output.
I want only that output in which numbers are followed by alphabet.
For eg: 55c     output:- 55
but for 55c5 or cc5 I don't want any result.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: If you only want numbers followed by letters, why is "33" output?

Comment: Numbers followed by only one or arbitrary number of characters?

Comment: He means that he doesn't want numbers where the letters are in front of it, not behind like an unit.

Comment: I want both individual numbers and numbers followed by letters.For Eg: 12volts and 12 volts should give me 12 as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word boundaries (`\\b`) to add the constraints you want. This will only match the number if it is immediately after a boundary, and if it is followed by nothing but letters (if anything) before the next word boundary.
Note that it uses a dedicated group to catch the number:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z]*\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("5N7BS is having a number 33 and 55c");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but this seems to do what you seek:

```
str = str.replaceAll(".*?(\\b(\\d+)[a-z]*\\b|$)", " $2").trim();
```

---

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "5N7BS is having a number 33 and 55c2 xyz";
str = str.replaceAll(".*?(\\b(\\d+)[a-z]*\\b|$)", " $2").trim();
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
33
```

Comment: For str = "5N7BS is having a number 33 and 55c5 xyz" it gives 3355c4 xyz as output. I want  individual numbers and numbers followed by letters only.

Comment: @Harki good point. I've fixed that problem. see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This too works, 1 or more occurence of digits but without any alphabets.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+[^a-zA-Z])+");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working :-)

```
package com.test;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class NumbersFollowedByAlphabet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "5N7BS is having a number 33 and 55c";
        char [] ch = s.toCharArray();
        int consecutive = 0;
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        String consecutiveNumber = "";
        for(char c : ch) {
            if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                consecutive++;
                consecutiveNumber += c;
            } else if(c == ' ' || Character.isLetter(c)) {
                if(consecutive >= 2 && c != ' ') {
                    list.add(consecutiveNumber);
                }
                consecutive = 0;
                consecutiveNumber = "";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use the shorter version:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+[^\\D]");
```